# MongoDB object type is not saved

Tags: javascript, mongodb

My user schema is the below.

```
var userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    //name:{type:String},
    username: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    password: {type:String, required:true},
    habit: {type:Object, required:true}
});
```

However, when I save new user (newbie) to mongoDB, only habit field is not saved.

```
var newbie=new User({
    username:username,
    password:password,
    habit:{}
});
console.log(newbie);
```

The result of the console.log(newbie) is "{ _id: ~~~????, username: 'babo', password: '1234' }", which does not contain habit field... How can I add habit?

Comment: What about `habit: {type:Object, default : {} }`

Comment: @JeremyThille even with `default: {}`, if `minimize: true` in the schema options it will still be removed / become undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default mongo doesn't save empty objects. So if you want to save an empty object you have to pass a second parameter `{ minimize: false }` to your `Schema`.

Use this code. This should solve your problem.

```
var userSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    //name:{type:String},
    username: {type:String, required:true, unique:true},
    password: {type:String, required:true},
    habit: {type:Object, required:true}
}, { minimize: false });
```